# Adding wavelength co-ordinates to pgfplots Smith Chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have currently been using the pgfplots smith chart

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Required for \varPsi below
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{smithchart}[
title=Smith Chart Stub Matching,
show origin,
width=20cm,
]
\end{smithchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the plot doesn't seem to have the wavelengths/degree measurements at the outside as it is shown in this diagram. I have checked the [manual (section 5.11)](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), and it doesn't seem to support this feature. Would this be hard to add manually? It is a bit beyond my skill level in pgfplots or tikz.

[image: Smith chart]

Anyway, im sure this would be an added feature that others would benefit from also.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: You can format your code, if it's an own paragraph, by inserted four whitespaces at each line start, or by marking the whole code snippet and pressing `{}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Multiple `axis` environments on top of each other can achieve your desired look.  I chose the "outer" axes to be `polaraxis`, so that the spacing is on the outer circles is regular. There is a circle with degrees, and also two circles in portions of the wavelength (in both directions, towards generator and towards load). For the polaraxes, the `xtick={...}` option requires a plot to be made or the `ymax` option to be set, in case you wonder about this option. There are also minor ticks on the wavelengths axes, in steps of 0.005λ.

The code with the superposed axes, still hardcoded for some labels and distances etc.:

```
\documentclass[a3,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}    
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}   
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xoffset}{10.45*(1-cos(3))-1.25}  
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yoffset}{sin(3)*10.45+9.2}  
      \draw[,thick,->] (+\xoffset,\yoffset) arc [radius=10.45cm,start angle=177,end angle=166];
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xoffset}{10.45*(1-cos(18))-1.25}  
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yoffset}{sin(18)*10.45+9.2} 
      \draw[,draw=none] (+\xoffset,\yoffset) arc [radius=10.45cm,start angle=162,end angle=144] node[midway,sloped]{towards};
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xoffset}{10.45*(1-cos(36))-1.25}  
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yoffset}{sin(36)*10.45+9.2} 
      \draw[,draw=none] (+\xoffset,\yoffset) arc [radius=10.45cm,start angle=144,end angle=126] node[midway,sloped]{generator};

      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xoffset}{9.95*(1-cos(-3))-0.75}  
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yoffset}{sin(-3)*9.95+9.2} 
      \draw[,thick,->] (\xoffset,\yoffset) arc [radius=9.95cm,start angle=183,end angle=193] ;
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xoffset}{9.95*(1-cos(-18))-0.75}  
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yoffset}{sin(-18)*9.95+9.2} 
      \draw[,draw=none] (+\xoffset,\yoffset) arc [radius=10.45cm,start angle=198,end angle=216] node[midway,sloped]{towards};
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xoffset}{9.95*(1-cos(-36))-0.75}  
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\yoffset}{sin(-36)*9.95+9.2} 
      \draw[,draw=none] (+\xoffset,\yoffset) arc [radius=10.45cm,start angle=216,end angle=234] node[midway,sloped]{load};


    \begin{polaraxis}[
                      rotate=180,
                      width=23cm,
                      xshift=1.5cm, 
                      yshift=1.5cm,
                      %xticklabels={$0\lambda$,$0.05\lambda$,$0.1\lambda$,$0.15\lambda$,$0.2\lambda$,$0.25\lambda$},
                      xticklabel style={
                          sloped like x axis={%
                              execute for upside down={\tikzset{anchor=south}},
                              reset nontranslations=false
                          },
                          anchor=north,
                      },
                      xticklabel={\small\pgfmathparse{0.5-\tick/720}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}$\lambda$},
                      xtick align=center,
                      xtick={0,18,...,360},
                      grid=none,
                      axis y line = none,
                      minor x tick num={4},
                      ymax=1,
                     ]   
   \end{polaraxis}

    \begin{polaraxis}[
                      rotate=180,
                      width=22cm,
                      xshift=1cm, 
                      yshift=1cm,
                      %xticklabels={$0\lambda$,$0.05\lambda$,$0.1\lambda$,$0.15\lambda$,$0.2\lambda$,$0.25\lambda$},
                      xticklabel style={
                          sloped like x axis={%
                              execute for upside down={\tikzset{anchor=south}},
                              reset nontranslations=false
                          },
                          anchor=north,
                      },
                      xticklabel={\small\pgfmathparse{\tick/720}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}$\lambda$},
                      xtick align=center,
                      xtick={0,18,...,360},
                      grid=none,
                      axis y line = none,
                      minor x tick num={4},
                      ymax=1,
                     ]    

    \end{polaraxis}



    \begin{polaraxis}[
                      width=21cm,
                      xshift=-0.5cm, 
                      yshift=-0.5cm,
                      %xticklabels={$0\lambda$,$0.05\lambda$,$0.1\lambda$,$0.15\lambda$,$0.2\lambda$,$0.25\lambda$},
                      xticklabel style={
                          sloped like x axis={%
                              execute for upside down={\tikzset{anchor=north}},
                              reset nontranslations=false
                          },
                          anchor=south,
                      },
                      xticklabel={\small\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\si{\degree}},
                      xtick align=center,
                      grid=none,
                      axis y line = none,
                     ]    
   \end{polaraxis}

   \begin{smithchart}[
                      show origin,
                      width=20cm,
                     ]
   \addplot[mark=none,line width=2]
       coordinates{
           (1, 0) (1, 0.1) (1,0.2) (1,0.3) (1,0.4) (1,0.5) (1,0.5)
       };
   \addplot[mark=none,line width=0.5]
       coordinates{
           (1, 0) (-0.3, 0)  % this one is not drawn outside!!!
       };
   \end{smithchart}
   \end{tikzpicture} 


\end{document}
```

And the result:
[image]

---

It might also be interesting to have a combined ZY smith chart. 
For this, just insert this code before the last `smithchart`

```
\begin{smithchart}[
                   width=20cm,
                   ticks=none,
                   grid style={gray!10!white},
                   smithchart mirrored,
                   few smithchart ticks,
                  ]
\end{smithchart}
```

for the result
[image]

Comment: Looking good thankyou,, im trying to work with it now, do u know how to get the labels to rotate the other way, and also how to start the 0lambda on the left. Im just trying to research it now

Comment: @JS60 Just wait some minutes. I'll also add other lambda-labels, for the other direction.

Comment: ok, ill just keep having a play around with it, looking good thanks

Comment: @JS60 Now it should be OK. Only thing I couldn't figure out is that the `xtick` option was not working for the `polaraxis`, so there too many steps for the wavelength on the outer two circles (in my opinion).

Comment: @JS60 see the edit for improved ticks for the wavelengths (including minor ticks), labels for the two directions and also a ZY version.... Now I'm quite happy with the result :)