# xtick in polaraxis useless

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, polarplot

As a followup question to [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304032/44467), I have a problem with the `polaraxis` of `pgfplots`. When I try to define `xtick`, nothing changes compared to dropping the option.

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}  
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[xtick={0,45,...,360},]   
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result (with x ticks in steps of 30° instead of 45°!)
[image: a simple polar axis]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your code I got the warning

> Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction ). Re
>   placing it with a default range and clearing all plots.

So if there is no plot inside the `polaraxis` environment set at least a value for `ymax`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}  
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
  xtick={0,45,...,360},
  ytick={0,.5,1},
  ymax=1.1
  ]
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Alternative:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}  
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
  xtick={0,45,...,360},
  ]
\addplot[draw=none]coordinates{(0,1)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One should never ignore warnings ;) , but somehow I missed this one....