# Symbolic radian coordinates in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I want to create a graph like the one shown in the figure (it is done with Geogebra), where on the *x-axis* there are labels in radians (for example `$\pi/6, \pi/4, \pi/2$` etc.) with its relative unit of measurement and on the `y-axis` values from `$0$` to `$+\infty$`.

[image]

In the meantime I have a difficulty to put the labels relative to the respective function maximums (in radians) where between `$0$` and `$\pi/2$` there are (5) five maximus of the green function `$f(x)=|\sin(10x)|$`. The violet function is `$g(x)=10|\cos(10x)|$` and between `$0$` and `$\pi/2$` there are six (6) maximus.

Into my MWE there are some differences:

1. I am not able to insert labels into radians (and for every maximum).
2. I can't get the same graph as with Geogebra.
3. I am not able to draw for the violet function for any point (for example `A`) its tangent to the graph to show that the slope is steeper than the green function.

Here my image with the MWE.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,xmax=8*pi,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ymin=0,ymax=10,
            axis on top,
            legend style={legend cell align=right,legend plot pos=right}]
\addplot[color=red,domain=0:7*pi,samples=101] {abs(sin(10*x))};
\addplot[color=green,domain=0:7*pi,samples=101] {10*abs(cos(10*x))};
\addlegendentry{$f(x)=|\sin(10x)|$}
\addlegendentry{$g(x)=10|\cos(10x)|$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I kindly ask for your valuable help and any improvement of my code is welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: @marmot Done! I always listen to the best when they're right. :-)

Comment: Mille grazie!!!

Comment: An off-topic suggestion: I noticed that you used the simple `|` as your absolute value delimiter. This creates wrong spacing when used together with `\sin` or `\cos`. Instead, use `\lvert\sin(10x)\rvert` and observe the correct spacing between the opening `|` and the `sin`.

Comment: @RuixiZhang Next time I'll try to change the code. Now I'm connected to a lucky location and I hope to remember to make the change.  Thank you and always good work. You're very talented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You can use `deg` to convert to radians.
2. Are you asking about the coloring or the background grid?
3. For the third part I use (a slightly modified version of) [Jake's great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198046/121799).
4. In order to add symbolic x ticks, I use a combination of [this answer by Peter Grill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34958/121799) and [that answer by Faekynn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304032/121799).

As for the question why the output of my previous answer did not resemble the GeoCobra result: I copied your question before the edit and did not realize that you added the factor of 10. I fixed that now. Note also that, if you plot 7 periods, it is advantageous to set the number of samples to `7*integer+1`, which is why I use `samples=99` instead of 101.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{fp} % for frac
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198046/121799
\def\parsenode[#1]#2\pgf@nil{%
    \tikzset{label node/.style={#1}}
    \def\nodetext{#2}
}

\tikzset{
    add node at x/.style 2 args={
        name path global=plot line,
        /pgfplots/execute at end plot visualization/.append={
                \begingroup
                \@ifnextchar[{\parsenode}{\parsenode[]}#2\pgf@nil
            \path [name path global = position line #1-1]
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) --
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
            \path [xshift=1pt, name path global = position line #1-2]
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) --
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
            \path [
                name intersections={
                    of={plot line and position line #1-1},
                    name=left intersection
                },
                name intersections={
                    of={plot line and position line #1-2},
                    name=right intersection
                },
                label node/.append style={pos=1}
            ] (left intersection-1) -- (right intersection-1)
            node [label node]{\nodetext};
            \endgroup
        }
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34958/121799
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0,...,7}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{\X*pi/10}
\ifnum\Y=1
\xdef\LstX{\myx}
\else
\xdef\LstX{\LstX,\myx}
\fi
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=12cm,height=7cm,
        tangent/.style args={at pos #1 with length #2}{
            add node at x={#1}{
                [
                    sloped, 
                    append after command={(\tikzlastnode.west) edge [thick, red!75!black] (\tikzlastnode.east)},
                    minimum width=#2
                ]
            }      
      }, 
      xtick=\LstX,
      xticklabel={\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{round(10*\tick/pi)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\mygcd}{gcd(\tmp,10)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mynumerator}{\tmp/\mygcd}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydenominator}{10/\mygcd}%
      \ifnum\mynumerator=0
       $\pgfmathprintnumber{0}$
      \else
       \ifnum\mynumerator=1
        $\frac{\pi}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\mydenominator}}$
       \else
        $\frac{\mynumerator\pi}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\mydenominator}}$
       \fi
      \fi}, % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304032/121799
            xmin=0,xmax=0.8*pi,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ymin=0,ymax=10,
            axis on top,
            legend style={legend cell align=right,legend plot pos=right}]
%           
\addplot[color=red,domain=0:0.7*pi,samples=99] {abs(sin(10*deg(x)))};
\addplot[color=green!60!black,domain=0:0.7*pi,samples=99,
tangent={at pos 0.1 with length 5cm}] {10*abs(cos(10*deg(x)))};
\addlegendentry{$f(x)=|\sin(10x)|$}
\addlegendentry{$g(x)=10|\cos(10x)|$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]