# How do I label the axis of a sinus using pi?

Tags: pgfplots, plot, grids, axis

I am plotting a sinus function using a pgfplot and would like that the tick of the x axis was labeled using multiplers of pi (pi/4, pi/2, 2*pi...), for they are the "important" x values to visualize when studying the sinus function.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[domain=0:2*pi, ymax=1.2, samples=100, grid=major,
  xlabel=$\alpha$, ylabel=$sin(\alpha)$, 
  xtick = {0,1,...,6}, ytick = {-1,-0.5,...,1}] %I assume this the part that I need to change?
    \addplot [blue](\x, {sin(\x r)});
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've tried giving regular values of pi in the braces near the % in the code above, but neither using "pi" nor "\pi" has proven useful. Am I missing something? The plot looks like this using the code above:

[image: This is the plot so far. Sorry for the size of the image.]

Comment: Does [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449176/121799) help you?

Comment: Yes! Not the answer exactly, but [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/axis-with-trigonometric-labels-in-pgfplots/34958#34958) posted in the comments. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an (simple) alternative:

- drawing `sin(x)` (in degrees)
- label tick with `0`, `\frac{\pi}{4}`, ....

  ```
  \documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
         grid,
         ymax = 1.2,
       xlabel = $\alpha$, ylabel=$\sin(\alpha)$,
        xtick = {0,45,...,360},
  xticklabels = {\mathstrut 0,
                  $\frac{ \pi}{4}$,$\frac{ \pi}{2}$,$\frac{3\pi}{4}$,$\mathstrut \pi$,
                  $\frac{5\pi}{4}$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$\frac{7\pi}{4}$,$\mathstrut2\pi$},
       domain = 0:360,
      samples = 73,
      no marks
                  ]
      \addplot +[very thick] {sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Here is a possibility. Notice that there exists a number format `frac`, but I was unable to make this work in this case.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34958/121799
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0,...,8}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{\X*pi/4}
\ifnum\Y=1
\xdef\LstX{\myx}
\else
\xdef\LstX{\LstX,\myx}
\fi
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:2*pi, ymax=1.2, samples=100, grid=major,
  xlabel=$\alpha$, ylabel=$\sin(\alpha)$, 
  xtick=\LstX,
      xticklabel={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{round(4*\tick/pi)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\mygcd}{gcd(\tmp,4)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mynumerator}{\tmp/\mygcd}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydenominator}{4/\mygcd}%
      \ifnum\mynumerator=0
       $\mathstrut\pgfmathprintnumber{0}$
      \else
       \ifnum\mynumerator=1
         \ifnum\mydenominator=1
          $\mathstrut\pi$       
         \else
          $\frac{\pi}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\mydenominator}}$     
         \fi
       \else
         \ifnum\mydenominator=1
          $\mathstrut\mynumerator\pi$       
         \else
          $\frac{\mynumerator\pi}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\mydenominator}}$
         \fi
       \fi
      \fi}, % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304032/121799
     ytick = {-1,-0.5,...,1}] %I assume this the part that I need to change?
    \addplot [blue](\x, {sin(deg(\x))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Update: The link I posted in the previous comment was a "dirty" escape for beginners like me ^^" but your answer is much more elegant and convenient. Thanks again!

Comment: @Álvaro Thanks, I guess it could be automatized much more. In principle, Ti*k*Z has very nice options, see e.g. on p. 949 of the pgfmanual the discussion on `/pgf/number format/frac whole=true|false`, however, numerical issues prevent me from using them... and even if you do `xticklabel={\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,frac, frac whole=false,
   /pgf/number format/frac shift=1}
   \pgfmathparse{\tick/pi}
    $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$`, then you still get ugly things like `1/1`...

Comment: Hmm I have however encountered an error while compiling. I am using Overleaf v1 and have received an error message saying: `Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, the operation 'gcd' has not yet b
een implemented in the floating point unit (in 'gcd(0.0,4)').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.41 \end{axis}`  Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: @Álvaro I do not get this error. However, I am wondering if it disappears if you replace `gcd(\tmp,4)` by `gcd(int(\tmp),4)`. (I'm using an up-to-date version of TeXLive 2018.)

Comment: I am afraid that the error persists... I guess I'll have to do it the dirty way xD. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: @Álvaro I actually *should* have used `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{round(4*\tick/pi)}` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{round(4*\tick/pi)}`, so my code worked by sheer luck on my machine. Does this replacement help you?

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't. I'm new to LaTeX, but I'm guessing that Overleaf v1 is just not up to date.

Comment: @Álvaro Sorry to hear that but I never used overleaf. All I know is that both `round` and `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` yield integers. I have been using the latter in *many* answers and in `\ifnum` conditions which are *really* allergic to `1.0`, and have never received a complaint. Is there a way you could update your overleaf distribution?