# Tikz graph for sine function of y=sin(2x+pi/3)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am looking to create the sine graph for function `y=sin(2x+pi/3)`, but it looks straight line.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis on top,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
 xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-1,ymax=1,ytick=\empty, 
 xtick={-3.66,-0.52,2.62},xticklabels={$\frac{-7\pi}{6}$,$\frac{-\pi}{6}$,$\frac{5\pi}{6}$,}]

\addplot []{sin(2*x+pi/3)}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the arguments of trigonometric functions are in degrees, so you need to convert them from radians to degrees to be able to feed them into the `sin` function. This can be achieved by wrapping the argument into `deg`, or by by using `trig format=rad`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis on top,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
 xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-1,ymax=1,ytick=\empty,trig format=rad, %<- 
 xtick={-7*pi/6,-pi/6,5*pi/6},xticklabels={$\frac{-7\pi}{6}$,$\frac{-\pi}{6}$,$\frac{5\pi}{6}$,}]

\addplot[samples=101,smooth]{sin(2*x+pi/3)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, can we have automatic xtick values, instead of defining like: -3.66, -0.52 etc

Comment: @ZEESHAN You could use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449778/121799) to do the labels automatically.

Comment: @ZEESHAN But the parser understands `xtick={-7*pi/6,-pi/6,5*pi/6}`. If you only have three labels, this might be the easier way to go.